# how to find the sum of the two selected columns from a big data file?

Tags: python, sum

I have a text file with "n" columns and many rows.
How can I use a for loop to find the sum of the square roots of the sum of the squares, row by row, starting from 1st and "n/2 th" columns?
For example, lets say my text file has 4 columns and 3 rows and looks like this:

```
    x11 x12 x13 x14
    x21 x22 x23 x24
    x31 x32 x33 x34
```

I want to find:

```
    Sq( x11**2 + x13**2 )+Sq( x21**2 + x23**2 )+Sq( x31**2 + x33**2 )
    Sq( x12**2 + x14**2 )+Sq( x22**2 + x24**2 )+Sq( x32**2 + x34**2 )
```

Comment: Please include a code snippet of what you've tried.

Comment: You want to square the numbers of both columns, and find the sum all those numbers from both columns?

Comment: Please update your question to include what you have tried so far and where that fell short.

Answer (score 0):

You are using python. Then you can make use of pandas package to process your data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Convert the file into pandas' dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_table('path_to_your_file', delimiter = " ", header=None)
```

You will get something like:

```
  | 0  1  2  3
--|------------
0 | x  x  x  x
1 | x  x  x  x
2 | x  x  x  x
```

Create function

```
def create_new(df):
    new_row = 0
    mid = df.shape[1]//2
    for i in range(0, mid):
        new_row += np.sqrt(df[i]**2+df[i+mid]**2)
    return new_row

df['n+1'] = df.apply(create_new, axis=1)
```

It will create a new column named `n+1` containing the calculation of each rows.

```
  | 0  1  2  3  n+1
--|------------------
0 | x  x  x  x   y
1 | x  x  x  x   y
2 | x  x  x  x   y
```

Comment: My columns don't have header, So I need sth like: col[1:n].

Comment: There might be many approaches. One that I can suggest is using python and to convert the file into pandas' DataFrame, by doing `pd.read_table()`